# Backbone router loads all libs again after every routing

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, cordova

I'm trying to create a Phonegap/Cordova Application with JQuery Mobile and Backbone. However after following [this](http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/03/using-backbone-js-with-jquery-mobile/) it seems like all libs get loaded again and phonegaps "deviceready" event gets fired again, when going back to the default route (In my case, "":"register"). Is this a normal behaviour? I would be fine with the loading but when trying to disable the deviceready event with document.removeEventListener after it got loaded the first time, the function would still be called when going back to the start page. Is there a way to suppress this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, this only happens on the "" : "something" route! Simply putting something in the "" and then calling the route in the init fixes the problem... JavaScript is absurd.